# How to specify one-way mapping in Dozer using annotations

Tags: dozer

How to specify one-way mapping in Dozer using annotation?
I can do that using XML Mapping as follows:

```
<field type="one-way">
    <a>oneFoo2</a>
    <b>oneFooPrime2</b>
</field>
```

However I don't see mention of this in annotation documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the current (5.5.1) version. As described in the [documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/annotations.html), there is only one annotation, @Mapping which tells the destination field to map.